# How can I use dynamic values in index.html on IIS?

Tags: iis

My problem is the common one that my website is an Angular SPA and the meta tags for SEO and Facebook etc are not visible to the various bots, except the static ones on the index.html.
There are many questions about this on SO and the usual answer is "you're stuffed, sorry, use SSR".

Using SSR for our whole site is not really an option right now so I'd like to find some other solution/bodge that doesn't use Javascript.

Is it possible to either edit the content of the index.html file before serving it, or serve different files based on the requesting URL (and, ideally, user agent for bots only)?
I have seen this and similar methods using Node like this: https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/

However we have IIS on a shared Hostgator server, so no access to IIS settings.

In short:
Is it possible to edit the meta tags content in index.html before returning the request, on IIS?

The URL would normally contain an ID, so I could even have a json file to map all the required values or something and pull it from here, if that is even possible...

Comment: "no access to IIS settings" usually means "No, impossible".

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was some way to do it on the default settings, or some tool along the lines of URL Rewrite.  If I did have access to the settings is there a way in IIS? I can always ask about changing them, plus it's relevant if we move to our own server and don't want to change to Node.

Comment: As far as l know, the iis outbound rule is used to rewrite the attribute in response like a,img,script tag in the html page, but this doesn't seem to meet your needs.